# Como evitar que me imprima el nombre del usuario logueado en un ciclo for - Django

Tags: python, django

estoy haciendo un proyecto en Django y necesito que el usuario que se encuentra logueado, no me aparezca en el ciclo for

Lo que tengo:

```
            {% for usuario in usuarios %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated %} #Aqui tengo que hacer la comparación pero no se como
                    <a href="" name="{{usuario}}">{{usuario}}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías cambiar la condición a `if user != usuario` eso solo si ambos objetos sean del mismo tipo o se garantice una correcta comparación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Algo así quizás? Pero revisa que los dos muestren nombre, ya que quizás user te devuelve el id y no el nombre y debas comparar user.name o como lo hayas llamado. Prueba y nos cuentas.

```
{% for usuario in usuarios %}
     {% if user.is_authenticated AND user != usuario %}
           <a href="" name="{{usuario}}">{{usuario}}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```